# IE11 memory leak when I have 500 rows in a list

Tags: html, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I have following elements in my list with 500 rows, when I open this page in IE11, it end up with almost 400mb memory in total, is there a way around this issue?

```
<a class="btn btn-small reply-action" title="Quick Reply">
    <i class="icon-share-alt"></i>
</a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the image file used is not being cached correctly. Could you include the css related to `.icon-share-alt`?

Comment: Please find the related css. Thanks

Comment: No, the actual css related to that class, not the computed styles in a screenshot.